# iOS application interface (storyboard) not update when running in another device

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I am having a big problem, i am programming an iOS application in Swift language, Xcode ver 11.3.1. The problem here is My app interface shows error when operating on other device. For example, in the storyboard, i set the View as: Iphone 8, storyboard will render the interface normally. But when I run on a device with a different resolution (ex. Iphone 11 Pro Max) , it will still display as on iPhone 8 (as the picture below). Does that mean The interface is rigidly installed in the storyboard, it is not updated according to the specific device screen. I tried running the project on many other Macbook but the problem is still there. The application did release in App Store but the error has not disappeared.
[Error displayed on iphone has a different resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2mOR.png)

[Storyboard is View as: Iphone 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jzss5.png)

Comment: have you set constrains to the view

Comment: @kjoe yes, i have